# Ajax php inserts some weird jquery code instead of question mark in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am building chat app and everything works fine except when user tries to send question mark. Every other character gets in mysql fine except "?" question mark which outputs this: jQuery110209582439290825278_1393250456239. Here is the code

```
    $('#send-message').submit( function(){
            var message = $('#send-message input[name=message]').val();

            if( $.trim( message ) == '' ){
            $('#send-message input[name=message]').focus();
            }
            var anon="<?php echo $anon; ?>";
            $.ajax({
                url: 'submit.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'message=' + message + '&anon=' + anon,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( payload ){
                    if( payload.status == 'error' ){
                        alert('Error!');
                    } else if( payload.status == 'empty-message' ){
                            $('#send-message input[name=message]').focus();
                    } else if( payload.status == 'success' ){

                        $('#send-message input[name=message]').val('');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

require_once('global.php');

$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = substr( $message, 0, 50 );
$anon=$_POST['anon'];

// For the sake of the demo lets clear some rows
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY msg_time DESC");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if( $num_rows > 15 ){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM messages ORDER BY msg_time ASC LIMIT 10");
}

if( $message != '' ){
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (msg_text, msg_time,anon) VALUES ('" . $message . "', '" . time() . "','$anon')");
    if( $insert ){
        die( json_encode( array( 'status' => 'success' ) ) );
    } else {
        die( json_encode( array( 'status' =>'error' ) ) );
    }
} else {
    die( json_encode( array( 'status' =>'empty-message' ) ) );
}
```

Comment: You must `encodeURIComponent` your message before inserting it into request string.

Comment: also do some sanitation of your data before adding to DB or use mysqli_* / PDO prepare statement !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because question marks are a reserved character (along with ampersands (&) and equals(=) and a few other characters they have a special meaning) - you need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) - like so:

```
$('#send-message').submit( function(){
        var message = $('#send-message input[name=message]').val();

        if( $.trim( message ) == '' ){
        $('#send-message input[name=message]').focus();
        }
        var anon="<?php echo $anon; ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submit.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'message=' + encodeURIComponent(message) + '&anon=' + encodeURIComponent(anon),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( payload ){
                if( payload.status == 'error' ){
                    alert('Error!');
                } else if( payload.status == 'empty-message' ){
                        $('#send-message input[name=message]').focus();
                } else if( payload.status == 'success' ){

                    $('#send-message input[name=message]').val('');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

*Edit:* Also should mention that the [mysql_* functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and you should switch to the mysqli or PDO connector (or if you don't upgrade that at at least for the sake of security escape all user input to your db calls)

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use htmlspecialchars() instead of encodeURIComponent() , as it does not attempt to apply unnecessary encoding to characters other than the few ASCII characters that really need it.

EDIT: (Thoughts):

As an alternative cant we use  htmlentities($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'); before sending the data ? Thoughts ?

Comment: Problem is, the `php` script may not even get the correct data (imagine `message` being something like `hell&com=a`) so there has to be some preparation done on the client side which is not covered by `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry i didnt get that thought. *Thinking more*